# How do I start an android activity if I want to know when it's over but I don't need a result or care if it was cancelled?

Tags: android, android-activity

Long Explaination follows.

My main activity A is starting 3 other activities B, C, and D in that order.

I need B to happen and either finish or be cancelled, then C here I do need to know if it was cancelled or a button was pressed then if C wasn't cancelled D will be started.

B is pretty much just a splash screen so I'd like to let the user skip it via the back button.  That's why I don't care how it finishes.  I just need to know when it finishes.  So A can start C.

C is like the main menu of the app.  So if the user backs out of it then I want to "exit" the application.  I'm not sure yet how I want that exit to happen but right now it's just A calling finish().  If the user picks a choice then other activities will get called from A and I'm just calling them D for now.  It will be a switch on the resultCode from C.

Should I just use startActivityForResult when starting A and then ignore what the result is or is there a better way I'm missing?

I'm not very familiar with android activities yet so it's completely possible I'm just missing something obvious in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to start C from B? That way you can handle launch of C and finish B in the button (or timer) event handler.

Comment: No, I want to avoid that so I can reuse the activity elsewhere and then go to something else other than C.  Like if there's a saved state I'd like to skip the menu and just go to wherever the app was before.

Comment: I ended up passing the intent to start C to B when I started it.  This let me finish the task.  I was hoping there was something like startActivityForResult that didn't mean passing around a useless parameter, but this works and that's good enough.